# Position with items in LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

How do I design an android application with two buttons next to each other (horizontal) and below these buttons i have a textview (vertical) using LinearLayout? Can't get it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
<TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Far better to use the RelativeLayout in this case.  You just described your desired result in terms of the items of your view *relative* to one another.  It is simpler to use than you might think.

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-relativelayout.html

Comment: Yeah, i've used RelativeLayout before, problem is I want to use weight on my buttons. Right now I have my buttons within a LinearLayout and TextView within a RelativeLayout, but it still wont seem to do what i want.